# Is there a way to use XQuery in symfony without installing a separate component?

Tags: xml, symfony, xquery

I am working with an xml document I need to manipulate it add elements delete element retrieve data etc...

I am using DOMDocument but better suggestions was to use XQuerry, i want a way to use Xquery inside symfony any suggestions ? I tried using DOMDocument and heard about Crawler that I dont fully understand if it makes possible to use Xquerry

Answer (score 0):

I think the simple answer is **NO**.

Your question is a bit misleading. If you do not want to install a separate package, then xquery would have to be supported by php. xquery 1.0 and xpath 2.0 share the same data model, operators and functions See: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xquery_intro.asp)

PHP only supports xpath 1.0. A request to implement xpath 2.0 was denied See: [Bug Report](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=80784&edit=3)

There may be some community projects, but I could not find any.

However, you can look into the XPathDom class from php. It supports xpath 1.0. Maybe that will make your task easier.

Comment: thank you for you answer, I want to install a package but with in symfony , I meant by other component another software or so, so I am working with docker I have symfony container, I dont want to create another container that will help in using XQuery